# Java-Sandbox example throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, runtime-error, sandbox

Anyone with experience using [Java-Sandbox](http://blog.datenwerke.net/p/java-sandbox-03-documentation.html), I have implemented one of the basic examples found in the documentation but i cant get it working.

Code:
SandPlayground.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import net.datenwerke.sandbox.*;
import net.datenwerke.sandbox.SandboxContext.AccessType;
import net.datenwerke.sandbox.SandboxContext.RuntimeMode;
import net.datenwerke.sandbox.SandboxedEnvironment;


public class SandPlayground {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Running...");


        SandboxService sandboxService = SandboxServiceImpl.initLocalSandboxService();

        // configure context
        SandboxContext context = new SandboxContext();
        //context.setRunRemote(true);
        context.setRunInThread(true);
        context.setMaximumRunTime(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, RuntimeMode.ABSOLUTE_TIME);
        context.addClassPermission(AccessType.PERMIT, "java.lang.System");
        context.addClassPermission(AccessType.PERMIT, "java.io.PrintStream");

        //run code in sandbox
        SandboxedCallResult<String> result = sandboxService.runSandboxed(MyEnvironment.class, context, "This is some value");

        // output result
        System.out.println(result.get());

    }

}
```

MyEnvironment.java

```
import net.datenwerke.sandbox.SandboxedEnvironment;
public class MyEnvironment implements SandboxedEnvironment<String> {

    private final String myValue;

    public MyEnvironment(String myValue){
       this.myValue = myValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
       /* run untrusted code */
       System.out.println(myValue);


       /* return some value */
       return "This is a different value";
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the error:

**EDIT**: I've included the dependencies, but I'm still getting some errors:

With the code above I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.datenwerke.sandbox.exception.SandboxedTaskKilledException: killed task as maxmimum runtime was exceeded
    at net.datenwerke.sandbox.SandboxMonitorDaemon.testRuntime(SandboxMonitorDaemon.java:82)
    at net.datenwerke.sandbox.SandboxMonitorDaemon.run(SandboxMonitorDaemon.java:57)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

and when i remove the context.setMaximumRunTime() call, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/IdentityMap ...
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely you are missing the javassist library (see the documentatio of the sandbox for dependencies: http://blog.datenwerke.net/p/the-java-sandbox.html). You'll find the javassist library on sourceforge at: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/Javassist/

The javaassist library is used to remove finalizers in loaded code. This can be turned off in the sandbox context:

```
contex.setRemoveFinalizers(false)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I totally missed the dependencies, but now that ive included them im getting new errors (ive edited the question), does the commons collections have so be a specific version, im currently using 4.4.0?

Comment: oh and i should probably mention that "This is some value" is being returned so I presume it has something to do with result.get()

Comment: The 4.0 is an alpha version, and i am not sure if it is meant to be compatible. Go for version 3.2.1

Comment: So from the release notes of commons collection 4.0 it says "For commons-collections, we have chosen to break the API in various ways". So I guess, the error you are seeing is resulting from an api change.